# How to efficiently duplicate a specific value in a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq

In C# how can I duplicate a value in a list?
I have found tons of solution smart solutions (especially in Linq) for how to remove but none on how to duplicate and in any case couldn't adapt to the code to my needs.

> E.g. if I want to duplicate 16 --> Lst   {0 0 12 13 **16** 0 3} ---> {0 0 12 13 **16 16** 0 3}

I wouldn't have to cycle on them but would prefer a single instruction

Thanks for helping

Patrick

Comment: What if it occurs multiple times? Duplicate all of them? Or does "I wouldn't have to cycle on them" mean just the first one? And do you want an in-place modification to the list, or do you want to get a new list with the item duplicated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own extension method that you can use the same way as the default LINQ methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Duplicate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, T toDuplicate)
{
    foreach(T item in input)
    {
        yield return item;
        if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, toDuplicate))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is

```
var test = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 12, 13, 16, 0, 3 };
var duplicated = test.Duplicate(16).ToList();
```

Comment: You could make it generic by using `object.Equals()` instead of `==` but then watch out for nulls!

Comment: To make it generic you could use the [default comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default) of type T: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, toDuplicate)`

Comment: @Matthew Watson: Thanks for the hint. I already updated the answer

Comment: Actually you should use Theodor's suggestion - Although `object.Equals()` would work, you would also have to check for nulls, which your current implementation doesn't do and will throw a `NullReferenceException` if any of the items are null. `EqualityComparer<T>.Equals()` does that for you.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
list.Insert((list.FindIndex(a => a== valueToBeDuplicated) + 1), valueToBeDuplicated));
```

so the `FindIndex(a => a == valueToBeDuplicated)` will get the index, then by adding `+ 1` will insert it on the next index.

Comment: Two problems with this. It will insert the `valueToBeDuplicated` at the beginning of the list if it's not already in the list.  Also it will only duplicate the fist instance of the value where as the other answers will duplicate all instances (that may or may not be desirable).

Answer (score 1):

A simple but maybe not optimal solution could be to combine the [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) and [`Repeat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat) operators:

```
var result = source.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, x == 16 ? 2 : 1));
```